# em.persist() required parent entity object in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

In the below code every time I need to get `Dept` object by passing `deptId` in `createUser()` when i am persist Emp, I don't want to go to a database.I want like JDBC to pass only id not object. Every time getting from database effects performance.  How do I do that?

```
public class Emp {
  Integer eid;
  String ename;
  long sal;
  Dept dept;    

  public void createUser(Integer eid,String ename,long sal,Integer deptId) {
    Dept dept = em.find(Dept.class,deptId);
    Emp emp = new Emp();
    emp.setEid(101);
    emp.setEname("Smith");
    emp.setSal(100000);
    emp.setDept(dept);    // here Dept object required 
    em.persist(emp);
  }

}

public class Dept {
  Integer deptid;
  String deptname;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [em.getReference()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) suits those needs

Answer (score 2):

Read the [API doc for EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)...

- getReference() - if you only need it as a reference (the instance might be lazily fetched according to the documentation)
- find() - if you want to use its attributes also

Comment: ppeterka is correct, you also use this for performance reasons... bare in mind (as in most cases with entities) that the state object can be detached.